# Modify Regex to get it to work in Google Sheets with Substitution?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to get rid of specific numbers in a cell using REGEXEXTRACT & SUBSTITUTE:

| Start with | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Charlie100db 2.Charlie 100dc, 3charlie 100 dcc,4 100charlie, 5. 100 charlie 1. Charlie100db, 2.Charlie 100dc, 3charlie 100 db, 4 100charlie, 5. 100 charlie, 6. Charlie100db Charlie100db | Charlie100db, Charlie 100dc, charlie 100 dcc, 100charlie, 100 charlie, Charlie100db, Charlie 100dc, charlie 100 db, 100charlie, 100 charlie, Charlie100db Charlie100db |

```
REGEXEXTRACT((SUBSTITUTE(A3,CHAR(10),", ")), "((?:\d{3,}|[a-zA-Z]\w+[^.])+)")
```

The Regex works to match test:

```
((?:\d{3,}|[a-zA-Z]\w+[^.])+)
```

[image]

Test code highlights as can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/KlU08z/1)

1. Charlie100db 2.Charlie 100dc, 3charlie 100 dcc,4 100charlie, 5. 100 charlie 1. Charlie100db, 2.Charlie 100dc, 3charlie 100 db, 4 100charlie, 5. 100 charlie, 6. Charlie100db Charlie100db

I believe this code should work in Google Sheets but it is failing, Im not sure why?

The shared google sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SssStTS63CztmUjjMRv3m2MBPAmPPmRT1CZI4Ym2_8A/edit?usp=sharing

Starting with the following text in A2: Charlie100db 2.Charlie 100dc, 3charlie 100 dcc,4 100charlie, 5. 100 charlie 1. Charlie100db, 2.Charlie 100dc, 3charlie 100 db, 4 100charlie, 5. 100 charlie, 6. Charlie100db Charlie100db

```
REGEXREPLACE(A2,"((?:\d{3,}|[a-zA-Z]\w+[^.])+)","")
```

Result=1. 2. 3 4  5.  . 2.3 4 5.  6.

However, using RegexExtract does not seem to work

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "((?:\d{3,}|[a-zA-Z]\w+[^.])+)")
```

Result=Charlie100db

Does anyone have a solution to fix this formula so that it works?

Comment: In general why don't REGEX that "work" independently work inside of google sheets? What is the best way to test REGEX for GOOGLE SHEETS using Regex101.com or a similar platform?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\n\d\.?|\d\.", ), ", \d|,\d", ", "))
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is almost there but still need to separate unique values using comma and space. for example: charlie300db, charlie 100dc...

Comment: @MMsmithH try: `=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\n\d\.?|\d\.", ", "), ", \d|,\d", ", "), "^, |,$", ))`

Comment: I think almost there but this formula still adds comma after comma in position where a comma exists 100charlie, ,